# Consistency OLS without intercept

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, economics, descriptive-statistics

I have this model without intercept

$y_i = \beta x_i + u_i$

where $\widehat{\beta} = \frac{\sum x_i y_i}{\sum x_i^2} = \beta + \frac{\sum x_i u_i}{\sum x_i^2}$

I want to verify the consistency of $\widehat{\beta}_1$.

¿Is it correct to say that $\sum x_i u_i \rightarrow Cov(x,u)$ and $\sum x_i^2 \rightarrow V(x)$?

Can you explain me why, please. Shouldn't they be in deviations from the mean?

Comment: Hi: If the OLS ( in non-stochastic case ) assumptions hold, then $cov(x,u) = 0$. The  concept of deviation from mean doesn't apply to $x$ in the non-stochastic case because it's not a random variable.